# Django override slugify globally

Tags: python, django

I've encountered a problem with Django's built-in `slugify` function. I'm building a website using Django framework. The site must have a forum app. After a bit of searching, I've found one. It works great, however, it's using the `slugify` function heavily on the topic titles to create "human readable" links to its pages. The problem is, we are writing in Russian, so as the result, it generates non-ASCII URLs which look like an unreadable mess of unicode data when trying to copy the link from the browser (and also throws an exception when trying to log them).

Is there a way to override the Django's `django.utils.text.slugify` globally for the whole project so I don't need to include half of the third party library only to change the `import` statements in their `models.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way where it is **not global** is to write your own slugify function and then you can utilise that by calling it in overridden save method of the model where you want to slugify the title/name field.

Eg.

```
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
  slug  = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     your_slugify_function(self, self.title)
     super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) model class with overriding the save method with slugify function. Like this:

```
class AbstractBase(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField()

   class Meta:
      abstract = True

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug = slugify.Slugify(self.slug)
       return super(AbstractBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And sub-class your rest of the models from this `abstract` class like:

```
class Post(AbstractBase):
   # rest of the post fields
```

In this way, `slugify`  will be done only in one place and work globally across all models.